# How to interpret TI Chronos watch accelerometer data

Tags: accelerometer, msp430

I've been trying for an embaressing amount of time to figure out how to interpret the wireless accelerometer data from the [TI Chronos](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/EZ430-Chronos?DCMP=Chronos&HQS=Other+PR+chronoswiki-pr). From my laptop with the usb-radio included, I read it into python basically following [this](http://pastebin.com/f71ca7188) recepie, then I throw it into a pyglet application to display the 3D acceleration vector. Its read in as unsigned chars, but I can't make any sense of the data. Neither have I find it documented anywhere. Here is an example printout from holding the watch still, while rotating it among 1 axis smoothly.

```
[253 245  24 255   6   7   1]
[  0 241  20 255   6   7 255]
[255 229  28 255   6   7 255]
[255 229  25 255   6   7 255]
[  1 229  19 255   6   7 255]
[249 224  21 255   6   7 255]
[254 219  17 255   6   7 255]
[255 218  11 255   6   7   1]
[247 211  15 255   6   7 255]
[251 209  10 255   6   7 255]
[251 212 255 255   6   7 255]
[243 194  16 255   6   7 255]
[243 200   7 255   6   7 255]
[247 197   3 255   6   7   1]
[246 190  10 255   6   7 255]
```

Obviously the first 3 bytes are the accelerometer data, and also clearly the numbers needs to be signed somehow. But why aren't the force vectors smooth? It's more obvious in the opengl visualization, but even in the small dataset above, one can observe for instance jumping from 255 to 1 in no time. Finally I want to get actual Gs from the data, but for now I'll settle with getting a smooth force vector that seems somewhat coherent with the rotation of the watch. Bonus points if anybody knows what the last 4 bytes means. Hopefully this is a chiphacker type question.

Comment: o_O  - An MSP430 dev kit with wireless, LCD, accelerometer, pressure, temperature, and battery voltage sensor that's ALSO a waterproof watch for $50!!!?!  Why did no one tell me about this?  BUY BUY BUY: http://search.digikey.com/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?Detail?name=296-25344-ND

Comment: They seem to be available again. Or were. The demand greatly exceeds the supply. Surely you've also seen the Launchpad?

Comment: Also, the waterproof part is a flat out lie.

Comment: @XTL - Yup, they're in at Digikey, Mouser, Newark, and Farnell; they filled the backstock on 7/30. Yes, I've seen the launchpad.  Concerning the waterproof part, according to the user manual, it's meant to resist occasional splashes or rain - Pressing the buttons when wet, or submerging it will damage it.  I hope you didn't learn this by experience!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the data is using [*signed* integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_integer_representations).

Therefore, 255 is -1, and 1 is +1.

Presumably, the forces are normalized somewhere, probably by taking a reading from the accelerometer when the watch is starting up. Afterwards, any increase in force is positive, and decrease in force is negative. That would seem to exactly match the given data.

Answer (score 2):

One of the other bytes is indicated if a button is pressed, I did some work on this ages ago ( [here](https://chemicaloliver.net/programming/receiving-ti-ez430-chronos-button-presses-in-processing-and-python/) ) the other two just indicate successful connection and whether you're in ppt or acc mode if I remember correctly.

I also had the same issue with the leaping values: [image]
<sub>(source: [chemicaloliver.net](https://chemicaloliver.net/images/chronosxyz.png))</sub>

It's almost like they did one direction 0+ and then the other direct subtracted it's value from 255. I thought (but never tried) ploting dx/dy/dz as I think that would give the movement you're looking for and would only require minor smoothing.

If anyone has more detailed information I'd be interested to hear too

Comment: The button is 0x10, 0x20, 0x30 added to the status byte in the reply. IIRC 0xff is "no data", 0x00 is no response and 0x01 is valid data.

The leaping sounds like you were treating the readings as unsigned.

Comment: A causa materialis for negative ("substracted from 255") values would also be the deceleration if you go from motion to rest (again).

Answer (score 1):

Check the accelerometer [family datasheet](http://www.vti.fi/en/products/accelerometers/consumer_electronics/cma3000_series/) linked in the wiki:

> *The acceleration data is presented in 2's complement format. At 0 g acceleration the output is ideally 0h.* [sic]

You will of course see gravity as a steady roughly 1 G vector in the output. If you have the control center or another working grapher, rotating the watch will show which axes are being pulled and which way.

If you've installed the [TI control center](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/EZ430-Chronos#Projects), you should also have the firmware sources for both the watch and the basestation. Reading these should tell you pretty exactly how the data is treated (almost not at all, some IIR filtering and periodical send when ACC is active). The basestation headers also contain info about the protocol between host and the basestation.

The other programming samples may also be of some practical help.

As for the "four extra bytes", I think your samples there are off sync. Looks like they are [4 5 6 0 1 2 3] Maybe you forgot to read the response for basestation start command or something. So the first three are from a previous request and the last four are from the current one and since you don't read all seven, the last three will come in at your next read etc. In correct order, the bytes are (IIRC): a start byte (0xff), command/response (0x06 = acc data follows), packet length (0x07 = seven bytes including these three),  "return code" && button state (0xff = no data), ax, ay, az. But you can find the real constants in one of the headers :)

Comment: Actually, Openchronos may be an even easier way to see some of the source:

http://github.com/poelzi/OpenChronos/blob/master/driver/vti_as.c

Comment: http://github.com/poelzi/OpenChronos/blob/master/logic/acceleration.c